# 階層関係にあるモデルのフォームが表示されない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

現在、階層関係にあるモデルのフォームを作成しております。
下記、モデルファイルになります。

**post.rb**

```
has_many :items
accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
```

**item.rb**

```
has_one :heading, dependent: :destroy
has_one :content, dependent: :destroy
has_one :link, dependent: :destroy
has_one :movie, dependent: :destroy
has_one :photo, dependent: :destroy
has_one :quate, dependent: :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :heading
accepts_nested_attributes_for :content
accepts_nested_attributes_for :link
accepts_nested_attributes_for :movie
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photo
accepts_nested_attributes_for :quate
```

**heading,content,link,movie,photo,quate.rb**
(こちらはheading.rb,conten.rb,link.rbとそれぞれモデルファイルがあるという意味です。そしてすべてに共通して下記設定がされています。)

```
belongs_to :item
```

---

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def new
        @post = current_user.posts.build
end

def create

    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|

        if @post.save
            format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'created!!' }
        else
            format.html { render :new }
        end
end

def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, :image,:user_id,
        items_attributes:[:id, :order,
            heading_attributes:[:id, :head],
            photo_attributes:[:id, :image, :title, :q_url],
            movie_attributes:[:id, :y_url],
            quate_attributes:[:id, :quate, :q_url, :q_title, :q_comment],
            content_attributes:[:id, :content],
            link_attributes:[:id, :url, :l_text],
            twitter_attributes:[:id, :t_url]
            ])
end
```

---

**posts/new_and_edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
    <% if @post.errors.any? %>
      <ul>
        <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>

<%= f.label :title %>
<%= f.text_field :title %>

<%= f.label :description%>
<%= f.text_field :description %>

<%= f.label :image %>
<%= f.file_field :image %>

<%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>

<%= f.submit %>

  <%= render 'posts/item_form_fields', name: 'headings' %>
  <%= render 'posts/item_form_fields', name: 'contents' %>
  <%= render 'posts/item_form_fields', name: 'movies' %>
  <%= render 'posts/item_form_fields', name: 'quates' %>
  <%= render 'posts/item_form_fields', name: 'links' %>
  <%= render 'posts/item_form_fields', name: 'photos' %>
```

**posts/_item_form_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@post, remote: false) do |m| %>
    <%= render 'items/form_fields', m: m, name: name %>
    <%= m.submit "作成" %>
<% end %>
```

**items/_form_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= m.fields_for :items, @item do |b| %>
  <%= b.hidden_field :order, value: '0' %>

  <%= render "#{name}/form_fields", b: b %>
<% end %>
```

**headings/_form_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= b.fields_for :heading, @item.build_heading do |h| %>
  <%= h.text_field :head %>
<% end %>
```

上記のように _form_fields.html.erb　をcontent,link,movie,photo,quateテーブル用にそれぞれもっています。

---

現在ローカル環境にて実行すると、子関係にあるフォーム(headingやcontent等)が表示されません。また、"作成"をクリックするとpost_controllerのpost_paramsにて下記エラーとなります。

> param is missing or the value is empty: post

どなたかお力添えいただけませんでしょうか？

Comment: (1)`posts/_item_form_fields.html.erb` が、`form_for`で始まっているので、このままだと、複数の`form` タグが出力されていることになりますが、ミスではなく、意図的なものでしょうか？ (2) @item に何が入っているか分からないので、値を入れている箇所のコードも記載していただけませんか？

Comment: @user3758624様
post_controllerの
`def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   @item = @post.items.build
   @is_edit = true
 end`

になります。(new.html.erbとedit.html.erbは new_and_edit.html.erbにrenderさしております。)
itemテーブルには　orderカラムをもたせており、このorderにより、post内のheading,movie等の順番を識別し、viewで表示ということをしたいのですが、イメージはNaverのユーザー投稿機能といった感じです。

Answer (score 0):

new actionの `@post = current_user.posts.build` を `@post = current_user.posts.items.build` にしてみてはどうですか
詳しくは ["Fields_for disappear when adding accepts_nested_attributes_for"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11769592/5989200)